# Fatal error: gl/glut.h: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm attempting to write a program and I keep getting this error:

```
Fatal error: gl/glut.h: no such file or directory
```

I've read through other similar problems that people were having, and nothing has worked for me. What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 32):

On Ubuntu 13.10 this file is available in the `freeglut3-dev` package.

```
$ sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

You must also be aware that C++ and Ubuntu are both case-sensitive. The correct include line in your program is:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

The upper-case "GL" is important.

Comment: I also encountered this problem on Kubutnu 20.04, I tried mentioned: `sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev` this didnt work.  `freeglut3-dev` helped at least.

Answer (score 0):

**On a Debian based system, do**

```
sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
```